# MYSQL: Data truncated for column 'mtf' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql

```
def MYSQLADD (code, lon, lat):

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="user",
        password="password",
        database="db"
    )

    finalres=present(lon,lat)

    print (type (finalres))

    print (finalres)

    for x in range (len (finalres)): #Trying to truncate 

        if len (finalres [x])>6:
            finalres[x]=finalres [x][0:6]
        finalres [x]=float (finalres [x])
        print (type (finalres [x]))

    finalres = finalres.append(1)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = """INSERT INTO 2var001 (mtf, el, atf, pm, wa, 
    mta, b6, b19, b16, p)
        VALUES ('finalres [0]', 'finalres [1]', 'finalres 
        [2]', 'finalres [3]', 'finalres [4]', 'finalres 
        [5]', 'finalres [6]', 'finalres [7]', 'finalres 
        [8]', 'finalres [9]')""";

    mycursor.execute(sql)

    mydb.commit()

    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")

MYSQLADD (001, -73, 43)



Error: mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): Data truncated for 
column 'mtf' at row 1
```

I converted each string to a float and I limited the number of decimal places it goes out to with the for loop above. Here is the array before and after the for loop:

```
['-13.3400001525878906', '671', '-7.63600015640258789', 
'125', '4.25199985504150391', '23.1439990997314453', 
'-13.8000001907348633', '314', '357']

[-13.34, 671.0, -7.636, 125.0, 4.2519, 23.143, -13.8, 
314.0, 357.0]
```

The values are limited to fewer decimal places so I am not sure why I still get an error.

Comment: what is the datatype for column `mtf`?

Comment: Mtf is a float. I converted all of them from string to float in the for loop above.

Comment: All of the columns datatype are float in table `2var001`?

Comment: Yes, they are all floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how to use VALUES in python sql statements. You don't need commas on VALUES. Below is an example

`cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))`

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO 2var001 VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (finalres [0], finalres [1], finalres [2], finalres [3], finalres [4], finalres [5], finalres [6], finalres [7], finalres [8], finalres [9]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable